# Perform calculation on a field in apex:column

Tags: visualforce

I have an extremely simple requirement. There is a table which shows files and each files size in bytes:

```
<apex:column value="{!file.BodyLength} bytes" />
```

I simply want to display the length in KB instead of bytes. I imagined VisualForce would allow something like the following:

```
<apex:column value="{!file.BodyLength / 1024} KB" />
```

But it doesn't. Is a formula field the only way to go about this? There is no simple way to do this directly in VisualForce?

Comment: I just created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/a144b140540f146e014680ed5ab02691) that shows it does work. What problem are you having?

Comment: If I try anything like <apex:column value="{!ml.Mileage__c / 100}" /> on a numeric field, I get the following error:

"Invalid field Mileage__c / 100 for SObject ... "

I'm not trying on the BodyLength field for now, but Mileage__c is a numeric field on another sObject and it should work here ...

Comment: As per sfdcfox, try <apex:column value="{!floor(file.BodyLength / 1024)} KB" />

Comment: @MehdiMaujood I was able to replicate the error with standard fields. I created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/40d37e091e02d179c5191e05a7ce5c46) that explains the problem and workaround.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the "value" attribute on apex:column has a bug in it. For now, you can expand your apex:column code to render the value within the apex:column's content:

```
<apex:column>
    {!ml.Milage__c / 100}
</apex:column>
```

I'm going to send an ask to salesforce.com and see if I find out why this is broken (and if it's going to be fixed).

Comment: I'm not surprised at this -- `value=` for some VF components has to resolve to a controller variable and expressions would be problematic; e.g. `<apex:outputField value="{!someInlineExpression}"/>`